# Pull to refresh on tableviewcontroller load

Tags: uitableview, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using a UIRefreshControl to enable the pull-to-refresh gesture on a table view.

I have used the storyboard te setup the RefershControl and in my TableViewController is use the following code to bound the method to the RefeshControl:

```
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("getData"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

At the end of the getData() method I call the reloadData() method on the tableview and the stopRefreshing() method on the refreshcontrol.

This is working fine. I can pull to refresh and the table gets updated.

Next thing I want is to start the RefreshControl when the TableViewController gets loaded. To show the user that the app is getting the data.
I tried to manually start the folowing code:

```
self.refreshCorntrol?.beginRefreshing()
getData()
```

It reloads the data but the animation is not working like it should. 
The table stays empty. Then when all the data is fetched the table is pulled down (like when I manually pull to refresh) en immediately pushed back up.

Anyone know if it is possible to change/fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Two things could be going on.

**1. UI Updates must be dispatched on the main thread.**

You're updating a tableView using it's `.reloadData()` method, which is considered an update to the UI. This being said, you must call `.reloadData()` on the main thread. While this should be done automatically for you already, I have run into some cases where I need to manually move it to the main thread. This can be done using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // Update UI ie. self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

inside your function.

**2. Programmatic pull refreshes don't always run for .valueChanged**

It is important to call `.valueChanged` (or, as you have it in your code, `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged`) when you call the pull refresh function, so that it is aware of what you are refreshing for. When the user pull refreshes, your program already does it, in the `forControlEvents` segment of your refreshController declaration. However, when you call it manually from your code, it does not do this by default. Instead, you have to pass the action using `sendActions`. This can be done by using

```
self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
self.refreshControl?.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
getData()
```

to call the pull refresh, rather than just calling `.beginRefreshing`

**Afterword**

I ran into a similar issue a few days ago, and posted the question on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799095/programmatic-beginrefresh-not-refreshing-data-in-uitableview) (I'm providing attribution in case you can find your answer there, and because it is where I took my first solution for you from).